# How to create a continuous line in a bar chart using combocharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets

Here's my code, I want to create a continuous line like a goal in my chart, I followed the example posted in [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart). Do I need to create a function to do that?

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 8],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['TV', 4],
  ['Gym', 2],
  ['Sleep', 8]
]);

  var options = {
  title:'My Average Day',
  vAxis: {title: 'Tasks'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Hours per Day'},
  seriesType:'bar',
  series:{4:{type:'line'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: you missed `:` in `series:{4{type:'line'}}`

Comment: Thank you! But now instead off the bar chart it turns into a line chart, even with the series Type setting on 'bar'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seriesType` should be "bars" not "bar" and your data should looks like this to draw line for 'Sleep' for example:

```js
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day', 'Sleep'],
  ['Work', 8, 8],
  ['Eat', 2, 8],
  ['TV', 4, 8],
  ['Gym', 2, 8],
]);



  var options = {
  title:'My Average Day',
  vAxis: {title: 'Tasks'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Hours per Day'},
  seriesType:'bars',
  series:{1:{type:'line'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```